# How to get all user information from Azure AD Graph based on list of users?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

If I have a large list of users, how can I return a list of the ones that exist in Azure AD via the Graph without a huge performance hit?

- Let's say the Azure Tenant has 30,000 users
- And we want to check a list of 1,000 users to see if they exist

I see two ways to do this:

1. Iterate over each user and check if that user exists, passing in a filter to the graph on the UPN
2. Query Azure for all users and intersect on that set. This results in 30,000 users being returned which requires paging (~30 pages) on the Azure side. This significantly reduces performance.

Is there a POST request where you can pass in users to match on? Is there a limit to the amount of data you can put in the filter on the GET request?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to Repro to GET only the List of user from the bulk users in AD.

Use endsWith or startsWith below query

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail, '@XXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail&$top=2

Make Sure ConsistencyLevel:eventual is added gives me the below result, which has search only top 2 as per the required data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how can someone get an intersect (via REST Request) with requested UPNs against those that exist in Azure AD?

Comment: I have edited my Answer based on the comment to fetch the requested Email available in AD with limiting with &$top=100 for now as a hint.

Comment: Thank you! Let's say you have a set of emails in code, e.g. ["email1@site.com", "email2@site.com", "email3@site.com", "nonactivedirectory@gmail.com"]. And we only want the subset that exist in Azure. Is there a way to say, here is my set, ["email1@site.com", "email2@site.com", "email3@site.com", "nonactivedirectory@gmail.com"] and only return ["email1@site.com", "email2@site.com", "email3@site.com"]. I see only 2 ways: (1) Get all users from the tenant, (2) query Azure AD per email. #1 is not performant when there are 1000's of AAD records. #2 is not performant when the code list is massive.